# What is "metrically free elements"?

Tags: phonology, syllables

According to the Free Element Condition, only metrically free elements may undergo metrical construction. But what is "metrically free elements"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is introduced in [Prince 1985](https://journals.linguisticsociety.org/proceedings/index.php/BLS/article/viewFile/1899/1671), who states that free elements are "those that are not already specified for the relevant metrical relation". For example, a syllable that is not already parsed into a foot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!